# How to authenticate the web services

Tags: .net, wcf

I am going to expose some web services which needs to be authenticated in a simple way without much complications. How would i need to proceed. please help

Comment: You can add an 'identification' property to inbound messages. This 'id' could be a string, like a GUID. On server, store a list of accepted ID's, if an inbound message does not contain an authorized ID, take no action. This may prove a simple solution for clients to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends heavily on the context. There are not the same options if we are talking for REST or SOAP web services. Perhaps [this MSDN post regarding authentication service in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.ASPX) could help you.

While you could use a custom cookie to authenticate user, I would suggest going with standard solutions like a membership api provider. Membership API is based on a token saved encrypted in a user cookie. If you want to implement a custom solution, you could follow the next steps:

- When the user authenticates, he gets a **token** which expires after 20 minutes or so, if the user does not act in that time
- The token is stored (encrypted) in a client side cookie
- The cookie is used in each client's http request
- The web service examines the user's cookie, extracts the token and concludes if the user is authenticated or not

Hope I helped!

Comment: The link which you have provided is good. I was doing this for the SOAP web services. Can I use cookie based authentication ? Is it good to use that kind of methods ? Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Comment: As I say in my edited answer, try to use standard methods and not a custom mechanism created by you.